# Save multiple checkbox values in database

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

i trying to save multiple checkbox values in mysql database, i searched a lot, but got how to print selected checkbox on screen but i didn't find how to save selected multiple checkbox into database.

my database structure is, i created one column as Hobbies in this if user select multiple hobbies, they all should save in one column(Hobbies)

This is my code:
HTML:

```
<table >

<tr>
<td width="26%">Hobbies</td>
<td ><input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" value="Drawing">Drawing</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" value="Singing" >Singing</td>
<td ><input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" value="Dancing" >Dancing</td>
<td ><input type="checkbox" name="Hobbies" value="Sketching" >Sketching</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Servlet:

```
String Hobbies[]=request.getParameterValues("Hobbies");
for(String hb : Hobbies) {
    String s=hb;
}   //taking data from html
ps.setString(13,s); // Inserting into database
// At this line im getting as "s cannot be resolved to a variable"
```

Comment: You did not find any article how to save data in a database? Unbelievable ... Additional, your compiler error is a completely other thing.

Comment: i want to save multiple selected checkbox values in one column of database. i searched but getting to print on screen but not find how save multiple selected values in single column

Answer (score 1):

Your error *s cannot be resolved to a variable" occurs due to you referencing the variable outside the loop where it was declared and defined.

Do the following instead:

```
String Hobbies[]=request.getParameterValues("Hobbies");
for(String hb : Hobbies) {
    // assuming ps.setString() inserts strings into your db
    ps.setString(13,hb);
}
```

**UPDATE / EDIT**

To make sure you store every value with a separate index, create an updating index for your loop:

```
String Hobbies[]=request.getParameterValues("Hobbies");
// create your index starting at the position for the first hobby
int hobbyIndex = 13; // assuming you want to start storing at index 13
for(String hb : Hobbies) {
    // assuming ps.setString() inserts strings into your db
    ps.setString(hobbyIndex,hb);
    hobbyIndex++;
}
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE / EDIT**

If you just want to store all hobbies in a semicolon separated `String`, then do

```
String[] Hobbies=request.getParameterValues("Hobbies");
// create your index starting at the position for the first hobby
int hobbyIndex = 13; // assuming you want to store all the hobbies at index 13
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < Hobbies.length; i++) {
    // push each hobby into a string builder at the end
    if (i == (Hobbies.length - 1)) {
        // do not append a semicolon after the last hobby
        sb.append(Hobbies[i];
    } else {
        // append the hobby and a semicolon
        sb.append(Hobbies[i]);
        sb.append(";");
    }
}
ps.setString(hobbyIndex,sb.toString());
```

I hope this helps or gives you an idea of how to achieve what you need.

Comment: This would only save the last entry since `ps.setString()` will always overwrite the previous value on index 13 (assuming it's a `PreparedStatement` which make sense in connection with a database).

Comment: Thank You, but it saving only one value, i am trying to save multiple selected values.

Comment: Yes, it just stores the value on index 13 and always overwrites the previously stored value... You will have to create a dynamical indexing. I cannot do that for you unless you provide more code related to the indexes.

Comment: @VIKASDUBBAKA How about you share the database structure so that we know **how** you want to store the hobbies exactly. Is ther a column 'hobbies' and you want  to store all hobbies as a concatenation or what? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50904187/edit) your question and add these crucial information.

Comment: my database structure is, i created one column as Hobbies in this if user select multiple hobbies, they all should save in one column(Hobbies)

Comment: How do you want to store them exactly? As a single `String` in one column? What if no hobby is chosen (`null` or empty `String`)? Choosing all (your example) hobbies would look like `Drawing;Singing;Dancing;Sketching` when delimited. What value type does your column for hobbies store? VARCHAR(...)?

Comment: This single line of code will convert string[] into semicolon separated String - `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.join(strArr,";");`

Comment: @deHaar  the value type of Hobbies is varchar(), if multiple hobbies selected means it should save in one column as Drawing, Singing, Dancing, Sketching.

Comment: @VIKASDUBBAKA Then just take my last example code and replace the semicolon (appended to the `StringBuilder`) by a comma. It should store all selected hobbies as a single comma separated `String`.